# Is calling non-member function from destructor OK?

Tags: c++, qt, crash, destructor

In C++, is it OK to call a non-member function (either a free function or a member of other objects) from within the destructor? I am calling a (non-virtual, although in this case it shouldn't really matter) method of an object of a different class. This method crashes on trying to access its members.

On the other hand, if this different object is a child of the destructed object (Qt), does this matter?

Comment: Why should it not be ok? The bug has to be somewhere else. (But note that there shouldn't be uncaught exceptions in destructors). (And one class inheriting from another shouldn't change anything)

Comment: Inherited objects are destroyed top-down. Consequently, trying to access something that belongs to the inherited object within the the destructor of the base object is undefined behaviour.

Comment: As long as it's not a virtual function, it should be ok.

Comment: It's better to add an example to demonstrate your problem ...

Comment: Your terminology doesn't make sense. What does it for an object to be a "child" of another object?

Comment: The child relation is something which Qt brings in. It is not an inherited object

Comment: You need a minimal test case. Your problem has nothing to do with destructors. It looks like you're using a dangling pointer. It may be that the pointer being dangling in a destructor is a side effect of other bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general a destructor can call any function it needs to properly destroy the object. However, there are a couple of caveats:

1. If the function called from a destructor throws an exception, the exception must be caught and handled in the destructor.
2. The function called from a destructor must not unconditionally create and destroy objects of the type to which the destructor belongs (since this will result in infinite recursion).